# Fix error when trying to rewrite callback example to a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to understand callbacks and promises using very simple examples. I figured out how to rewrite an example of why you need callbacks into a working "callback form". However, I'm stuck on rewriting this into a promise

I have tried to make this work as a promise following the example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Basic_Example

But I'm having some trouble making it work.

First I got this code showing why callbacks are important:

```
function first(){
  // Simulate a code delay
  setTimeout( function(){
    console.log(1);
  }, 500 );
}

function second(){
  console.log(2);
}

first();
second();
```

I then rewrote this using callbacks:

```
function first(callback){
  // Simulate a code delay
  setTimeout( function(){
      console.log(1);
      callback();
  }, 500 );

}

function second(){
  console.log(2);
}

first(second);
// second();
```

Now I'm wondering how to rewrite this as a promise.

```
let first = new Promise( function (resolve, reject){
    // Simulate a code delay
  setTimeout( function(){
      console.log(1);
      resolve('success')
  }, 500 );
});

function second(){
  console.log(2);
}

first.then(second());
```

What I want it to output is first 1 and then 2, now it ouputs 2, then 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the code that should do what you're asking.
The problem in your code is that you're actually calling second() immediately:

`first.then(second());`

instead of passing the function as the argument (`then()` will call it when the first promise is resolved):

```
let first = new Promise( function (resolve, reject){
    // Simulate a code delay
  setTimeout( function(){
      console.log(1);
      resolve('success')
  }, 500 );
});

function second(){
  console.log(2);
}

first.then(second);
```

Comment: ^ This. To clarify, when you write a function name with parentheses, like `second()`, you're calling the function and running its code. When you write a function name without parentheses, like `second`, you're *referencing* that function, which means it's acting like a variable that you can pass around -- for instance, as the callback in a `then()` handler.